# Retrieve value from dropdownlist using LINQ and show result in textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I want to retrieve value from dropdownlist and display the result on textbox by LINQ but this code retrieves employee number1 only?

```
Employee employee = north.Employees.Single(q=> q.EmployeeID == int.Parse(DropDownList2.SelectedValue));
employee.FirstName = TextBox5.Text;
employee.LastName = TextBox6.Text;
north.SubmitChanges();

View();
```

Comment: your linq code return one employee because you are using method "Single"

Comment: What you are trying to do here. You want single/Multiple results?

Comment: What he (probably) means is that t works only for the first index of dropdown.

Comment: The reason the code returns only number 1 may have something to do with `SelectedValue`, which if you do not properly set the `DataSource`, then the value will be 0 ...

Comment: You know, writing a 'pretty and short code' without knowing how to debug it is not a good practice.
Why don't you iterate with a simple loop over the DropDownList collection and see by yourself if all data is correct?
Then, After getting things clear, go back to LINQ.

Comment: hey guys i want to delete row in employee table by select id from drobdownlist i want the code to work what i do ?

Answer (score 1):

There's probably something wrong with your data binding. I suppose `SelectedValue` always returns 0. For a workaround, try `int.Parse(DropDownList2.SelectedItem.Text)` (Note that if your items' values are different from their text, you cannot use this.)

Comment: hey guys i want to delete row from DB by select id from dropdownlist what i do to run the code i want  it's run